# React detect level of nestedness relative to component

Tags: reactjs

I couldn't find any solutions with google, so I am wondering if it's possible to do. Lets say I have react components as follows:

```
<Root>
  <Child>
    <DeepChild/>
  <Child>
</Root>
```

Is it somehow possible to find out the level of nestedness of `Deepchild` relative to `Root`? For example by using a custom hook.

I know it could just pass the nested level as prop, but I want to know whether there is a solution that does not invole passing the level of nestedness as prop. For example a native javascript solution based on `ref` or `id` or somehow with react context.

Answer (score 0):

I got some ideas, first is using React "Children" API:

```
const RootContainer = (props) => {
  console.log(Children.toArray(props.children));
  return props.children;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <RootContainer>
      <div id="root">
        <div id="child">
          <div id="deep-child"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </RootContainer>
  );
}
```

Through the root container component, you are able to operate the root component reference.
And every component that contains children React nodes has a "props" property that contains a "children" property.
With that, you can recursively query the number of the components level.

The second is using "ref" or "id" to get the specific DOM element reference and judge the element whether has children:

```
export default function App() {
  const rootRef = useRef(null);
  console.log(rootRef);
  return (
    <RootContainer>
      <div id="root" ref={rootRef}>
        <div id="child">
          <div id="deep-child"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </RootContainer>
  );
}
```